# Adding items to a deque() via a generator

Tags: python-3.x, deque

I have a prime number generator.  The yielded items are cast into a list.  I can reference any item in the list.

```
def primes(limit):
    yield 2
    if limit < 3:
        return
    lmtbf = (limit - 3) // 2
    buf = [True] * (lmtbf + 1)
    for i in range((int(limit ** 0.5) - 3) // 2 + 1):
        if buf[i]:
            p = i + i + 3
            s = p * (i + 1) + i
            buf[s::p] = [False] * ((lmtbf - s) // p + 1)
    for i in range(lmtbf + 1):
        if buf[i]:
            yield i + i + 3


x = list(primes(100))
print(x)
print(len(x), '\n')
```

Output:

```
[2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97]
25
```

The problem is if I use x = list(primes(num)) with a very large number then the resultant list becomes
extremely large.

All I want are the last n (the largest) items in the list, but I would to be able to vary n.

I thought a deque() would be perfect for this.  I was looking through documentation and I found: Appending to a deque that is full (len(d) == d.maxlen) discards items from the other end.

This, combined with the ability to specify a maxlen=n at queue creation is exactly what I want.

With that in mind, I tried this:

```
from collections import deque


def primes(limit):
    yield 2
    if limit < 3:
        return
    lmtbf = (limit - 3) // 2
    buf = [True] * (lmtbf + 1)
    for i in range((int(limit ** 0.5) - 3) // 2 + 1):
        if buf[i]:
            p = i + i + 3
            s = p * (i + 1) + i
            buf[s::p] = [False] * ((lmtbf - s) // p + 1)
    for i in range(lmtbf + 1):
        if buf[i]:
            yield i + i + 3


x = deque([primes(100)], maxlen=10)
# x = list(primes(100))
print(x)
print(len(x), '\n')
```

But what I get is this:

```
deque([<generator object primes at 0x0000025ED8449C80>], maxlen=10)
1
```

I also tried:

```
for i in x:
    print(x)
```

But that also does not work.

How can I use deque() as I described above to get my desired result?

I need to be able to print out the contents of the deque, which should be the last n items from the generator.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out:  x = deque([x for x in primes(100)], maxlen=10)

deque([53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97], maxlen=10)
10

x = deque([x for x in primes(1000)], maxlen=10)

deque([937, 941, 947, 953, 967, 971, 977, 983, 991, 997], maxlen=10)
10